# UIWebView not displaying user name after logging in

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, uiwebview

I'm working on a WebView app using `UIWebView` for iOS (ObjC). The app has a login feature which is created to be parsed using className.

According to the log the app is getting the username but it's not loading it in and is stuck with **Hello, Sign In** message. I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to log user logged in or not. The Menu not reloading to display "Welcome USERNAME" as it should be.

The code as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WIDTH = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;

    logoutURL = @"http://XXXXdomain.com/index.php?a=logout&type=app";

    preferences = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
    NSString *savedSessionId = [preferences objectForKey:@"sessionId"];
    islogedin = [preferences objectForKey:@"islogedin"];
    userName = @"";
    if([preferences objectForKey:@"userName"]){
        userName = [preferences objectForKey:@"userName"];
    }
    if([islogedin isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        NSLog(@"arrNavigation=======%@---------%ld", arrNavigation, (long)openSection);
        [self reloadMenu];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setName:) name:@"name" object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMenu) name:@"reloadMenu" object:nil];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"arrNavigation=======%@---------%ld", arrNavigation, (long)openSection);
        [self reloadMenu];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setLogout:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMenu) name:@"reloadMenu" object:nil];
    }
}

-(void)setName:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"logged in & received--------");
    NSString *name = [notification object];
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", name];
    [signinBtn setTitle:msg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoutBtn.hidden = NO;
    islogedin = @"true";
}

-(void)setLogout:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"loggedout--------");
    //NSString *name = [notification object];
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, Sign In"];
    [signinBtn setTitle:msg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoutBtn.hidden = YES;
    islogedin = @"false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the code is related to another activity and should define the loop of login session.

Sorting your code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    WIDTH = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;

    logoutURL = @"http://XXXXdomain.com/index.php?a=logout&type=app";

    preferences = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
    //NSString *savedSessionId = [preferences objectForKey:@"sessionId"];
    islogedin = [preferences objectForKey:@"islogedin"];
    userName = @"";
    if([preferences objectForKey:@"userName"]){
        userName = [preferences objectForKey:@"userName"];
    }
    if([islogedin isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", userName];
        [signinBtn setTitle:msg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        logoutBtn.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        [signinBtn setTitle:@"Hello, Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        logoutBtn.hidden = YES;
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"arrNavigation=======%@---------%ld", arrNavigation, (long)openSection);
    [self reloadMenu];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setName:) name:@"name" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMenu) name:@"reloadMenu" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setLogout:) name:@"logout" object:nil];

}

-(void)setName:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"logged in & received--------");
    NSString *name = [notification object];
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", name];
    [signinBtn setTitle:msg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoutBtn.hidden = NO;
    islogedin = @"true";
}

-(void)setLogout:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"loggedout--------");
    //NSString *name = [notification object];
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, Sign In"];
    [signinBtn setTitle:msg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    logoutBtn.hidden = YES;
    islogedin = @"false";
}
```

Hope this solve the problem.